# Creating Silverlight 3 applications with F#

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, f#

Is there an easy way to create Silverlight 3 applications with F# (October CTP)? 
I have seen the [F# for Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpsilverlight), but that only works with the May CTP.

I am using Visual Studio Integrated Shell 2008.

Comment: [Here](http://ryoushin.com/cmerighi/en-us/79,2009-07-01/Silverlight_and_F_happily_ever_after.aspx) is an article.

Comment: That only works with the May CTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use the May CTP templates with the October CTP version of F#

Create your new project, then unload it and edit the hint path for the FSharp.Core.dll to point to the October CTP,

```
<HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\fsharp-1.9.7.8\Silverlight\2.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
```

then reload the project and build.

You do have to package the .xap file manually by e.g. using the `chiron` tool (or just zipping and renaming)

The AppManifest.xaml file looks like

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            RuntimeVersion="3.0.40818.0" 
            EntryPointAssembly="astroclock-fs" 
            EntryPointType="astroclock.fs.MyApp">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="astroclock-fs" Source="astroclock-fs.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="FSharp.Core" Source="FSharp.Core.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

where you fill in your own assembly name and entrypoint instead of mine

Create a folder in $(ProjectDir) to hold all the files to be packaged and copy C:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.7.8\Silverlight\2.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll into it, along with the AppManifest.xaml above

Create an empty file null.py in the folder to keep chiron quiet if you are using that tool

Add the following post-build steps

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
copy /y $(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) [your directory with all the output] 
"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.0\Silverlight\bin\chiron.exe" /d:[your directory with all the output] /z:app.xap
```

Create a test page to load app.xap

Build project

Load page in browser and enjoy

ADDED

You can make a permanent fix for the hint path needed to find FSharp.Core.dll by editing the template in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\FSharp\Silverlight\SilverlightLibrary3.zip\SilverlightLibrary.fsproj (and probably the version of the file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\FSharp\Silverlight\SilverlightLibrary3.zip just to be certain).

And a working proof of concept (source and everything bundled into the xap) [here](http://www.stevegilham.com/silverlight/astroclock.fs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got to wait for [VS 2010](http://silverlighthack.com/post/2009/11/04/Silverlight-3-and-FSharp-Support-in-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx).

Comment: There also you can only create a class library.